# Multiplying linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have two linear transformations, A and B, on a 2-dimensional vector space.
$$A=w(ax+by)=aw(x)+bw(y)\\ B=w(cx+dy)=cw(x)+dw(y)$$ I want to find $AB$ which is $(aw(x)+bw(y))(cw(x)+dw(y))$. I know that I need to foil this out to $aw(x)cw(x)+aw(x)dw(y)+bw(y)cw(x)+bw(y)dw(y)$. How do I simplify this more?

Comment: I think you better read the easy directions to write mathematics in this site, as your post is very hard to understand as it is now.

Comment: This is rather unusual notation -- usually $AB$, where $A$ and $B$ are linear transformations, would denote the linear transformation obtained by applying first $B$ and then $A$, not the non-linear product of the results of applying $A$ and $B$. Also, the displayed equations don't seem to make sense, both because $A$ and $B$ seem to be equated to vectors (this could be remedied by replacing the equal signs e.g. by colons), and because the equations, as far as they make sense, seem to say $A=w=B$.

Comment: I see what you're saying... maybe I should just use matrix notation...